# How to handle GoogleApiClient on Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-api-client

I have a `ViewPager` which contains various `Fragments`. In one of them I'm calling the Google Places Api to retrieve some data based on my input. Later, when I go to the next `Fragment`, if I want to return back to the previous `Fragment` (to introduce another input), I can't retrieve data.

Code below:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    /* init my components */

    Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer buffer) {
                        /* do my stuff */
                    }
                });
    return v;
}
```

My problem is, when I'm turning back from the next `Fragment` and insert another input immediately, I can't reach the onResult because mGoogleApiClient disconnects before getting the callback result. I have to insert it twice to make it work.

I'm guessing I have problems handling my mGoogleApiClient object through the `Fragment`'s lifecycle. Debugging my application I found out that there are two different objects mGoogleApiClient in memory due to the recreation of the `Fragment`'s `View` (going forward and back again in muy `ViewPager`).

Is there a way to handling the `GoogleApiClient` instance or the connection itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you misunderstand purpose of Fragment - it is just UI (and Activity too). Do not put business logic, such as fetching data in it. Create separate 'model' class, which will be stored in Application (maybe Activity) and bound to lifecycle of that Application(Activity). Provide those data by some interface Activity implel

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm upvoting because you're right about the approach, but it doesn't solve my question.